# Using VisualVM with a JDK1.4 application?

Tags: java, visualvm, jdk1.4

I'm interested in using VisualVM (running on a JDK 1.6 environment) to monitor and troubleshoot some issues with an application deployed and running on JDK 1.4 (and Tomcat 5.0).

Basically, the app is hanging periodically and I am interested in seeing if I can monitor it to help find out where.

The homepage for VisualVM mentions that it can work with JDK1.4 apps, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to enable the 1.4  app/server to listen on a JMX port to accept my connection.

Has anyone hooked up VisualVM before to a 1.4 environment that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify your application to provide JMX beans - they are not included in JVM by default. See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html for more information how to achieve that.